# What threadsafe inmemory c# collection to use?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a requirement where I want to save a key and a object in memory (Total of about 10 values) through one class and I want to be able to update this collection in about every 30 seconds 
and then be able to use this in memory collection for my calculations in other class. Initially I decided to use IDistributed Cache but then one of my colleague suggested some kind of inmemory threadsafe collection as there are chances of cache getting cleared if I don't update the values for a longer period of time. Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a ConcurrentDictionary for this, it's thread safe.

> Represents a thread-safe collection of key/value pairs that can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2

As you say, a cache **could** get cleared at anytime .
Using a Dictionary is also a kind of a cache but you will not have to deal with expirations and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) if you want to be able to change keys and/or values at any time and your values are valid independent of each other.

If you need to update the whole data structure at one time (e.g. the producer will always update the data in one sweep and the consumer is not allowed to read during this update), you will need some kind of locking anyway. In this case you can use a normal [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) with a `lock` or [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=netframework-4.8) if you have multiple consumers